# Difference between greedy and Dynamic and divide and conquer algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I want to know the difference between these three i know that in Divide and conquer and Dynamic algos the difference between these two is that both divides the broblem in small part but in D&Q the the small parts of the problem are  dependent on each other whereas not the case with dynamic. but what about greedy ?

Comment: @MitchWheat i just want to know about Greedy algo. how it is different from dynamic and D&Q. rest is Ok. I couldn't understand properly on google.

Comment: That always depends on the problem and the actual implementation. However, reading about [what a greedy algorithm meanse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) should give you an answer.

Comment: @ShekharSingh: Tell us what you found and what you did not understand so that we can help you. Otherwise we won't do better than repeating your google results.

Comment: D&Q and greedy are not completely different classes of algorithms, an algorithm can be both (for example, binary search).

Comment: @Bergi what i have understood is that for each time we take the best case in greedy algorithm but not the case with others.And thats why the overall performaance is not optimal. Am i write ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science. Consider asking it at cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a simplified view outlining the gist of both schemes:

- greedy algorithms neither postpone nor revise their decisions (ie. no backtracking).
- d&q algorithms merge the results of the very same algo applied to subsets of the data

examples:

- greedy: kruskal's minimal spanning tree
  select an edge from a sorted list, check, decide, never visit it again.
- d&q: merge sort
  split the data set into 2 halves,
  merge sort them,
  combine the results by skimming through both partial results in parallel, stopping, choosing or advancing as appropriate.

Comment: thats like giving the exact answer Thanks  Collapsar